Can I change $4 \ \text{cm}$ to $4.000 \ \text{cm}$ if I want to divide it by $0.127$ to make it appear in $4$ sig figs?
I need to write a report on angle and length. Can I change, for example, $4 \ \text{cm}$ to $4.0 \ \text{cm}, \ 4.00 \ \text{cm}$ or $4.000 \ \text{cm}$ as I like if I want to make the division sig fig result as I desire? 
So, for example, $\dfrac{4.000}{0.127}= 31.50$ with sig fig rule.
Like this: 

If you measured to 1 significant digit, you can’t add 0’s at the end of that 1 significant digit.

"numerical data are presented in a manner that implies better precision than is justified" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision .   "it would create false precision to present a measurement as 12.34525 kg when the measuring instrument only provides accuracy to the nearest gram (0.001 kg)."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

As a general, rule of thumb rule (using significant digits is a rule of thumb rule), carry your internal calculations to a high precision, but then report to the precision that is justified by the data.
If you measured that $4 \ \text{cm}$ to within three or four millimeters of $4 \ \text{cm}$, you should report that $4 \ \text{cm}$ is $4 \ \text{cm}$, and you should report the final result ($4/0.127 \approx 31.496$) as $30$, rather than $31.496$. If you measured that $4 \ \text{cm}$ accurately to the sub-millimeter level, you should report that length as $4.0 \ \text{cm}$ rather than $4 \ \text{cm}$, and the result as $31$ (not $31.0$). Similarly, a reading you can trust as truly being $4.00 \ \text{cm}$ with a high degree of certainty, report the reading as $4.00 \ \text{cm}$ and the result of the division as $31.5$.
You will need to go past the digits of precision rule if you want to do statistics more accurately.
